# Remote-function error on (un)maximize

Tags: electron

I am trying to get the events 'maximize' and 'minimize' but there's an error **sometimes** occuring:

Code:

```
{remote} = require("electron");

remote.getCurrentWindow().on('unmaximize', function(){
    // code
});
remote.getCurrentWindow().on('maximize', function(){
    // code
});
```

Error:

[image: The Error]

I don't know what this error means but the program quits after I click "OK".

*"Function provided here: main.js:**408:27**"* <- This line number doesn't even exist in my main.js code!!!

EDIT: The error occurs when the minimized window is shown.